# Node js line by line module

Tags: node.js

I using line-by-line module for node js. I want to start parse lines on specific line I using this:

```
lr = new LineByLineReader('test.txt', {
    start: 10
});
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: "this doesn't work" — What does that mean? Does it throw an error? Does it start from line 1? You should provide a [mcve] and a *clear problem statement*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/line-by-line):

> You can also pass start and end position **in bytes** to read from file
>   region:
>
> ```
> { encoding: 'utf8',
>   skipEmptyLines: true,
>   start: 1000 }
> ```

Your instruction says to start at **byte** 10 not *line* 10.

If you want to skip lines, you'll have to keep count of them yourself.

```
const LineByLineReader = require("line-by-line");
const lr = new LineByLineReader("data.txt");
let lineCount = 0;

lr.on("line", function(line) {
    lineCount++;
    if (lineCount < 10) {
        return;
    }
    console.log(line);
});
```